# How are the data types in dsin.txt defined?

Tags: types, modelica, dymola

I am currently developing a python interface for running Modelica simulations using Dymola and I can't find any documentation on the data types used in the `dsin.txt` file :

```
...
 0   0   0    0   4  328   # timeToEmpty
-1   0   0  100   2  272   # level
 0   0   0    0   3  256   # der(level)
-1  10   0    0   1  280   # initialFlowRate
 0   0   0    0   6  320   # flowRate
...
```

There is some documentation inside the file itself, but it's not very helpful :

```
...
# column 6: Data type of variable.
#           = 0: real.
#           = 1: boolean.
#           = 2: integer.
...
```

As you can see, the types I'm getting are completely different than the ones described. I want to know if the data is of type `Real`, `Integer`, `Boolean` or something else to adapt the representation in my interface accordingly.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49065763/extract-types-classnames-from-flat-modelica-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking everywhere, i found that the description of the variables contain a text field in brackets at the end where the unit, the display unit and the type are written, if it is not `Real`. I only need to parse it.

Answer (score 2):

Did you have a look at [ModelicaRes](http://kdavies4.github.io/ModelicaRes/)? It might already have built in the functions you are looking for.

Comment: I didn't find any documented function that does the conversion, but I will search in the code to see if they do it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I cannot help you to indentify the types either, but for running Modelica simulations using Dymola you can also have a look at [BuildingsPy](https://github.com/lbl-srg/BuildingsPy), which uses .mos-Scripts to run and setup simulations in Dymola.